# Como poner el foco sobre un control

Tags: c#

[image: **Text Box**]

Me gustaria saber como hago para que al momento de abrir la aplicaion de windowws form me ponga el cursor en la text box de ID Cliente.

No se si tenga que codificar algo o habilitar alguna propiedad de la caja de texto espero me puedan asistir

Comment: Esta pregunta ya existe en stackoverflow en inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597196/how-to-put-focus-on-textbox-when-the-form-load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

También puedes hacer lo siguiente en el evento Load del formulario, suponiendo que tu textBox se llama txtIdCliente:
txtIdCliente.Focus();

Pero lo que yo haría es establecer un orden de los controles en tu formulario. Seleccionas el control(textBox Id Cliente), luego te vas a la propiedad TabIndex y a esta le pones 0, luego seleccionas el segundo control y en TabIndex le pones 1 y así sucesivamente. Si lo haces así al cargar el formulario el foco se estable en el control con el TabIndex mas bajo.

Comment: muchas gracias por el aporte solucionaste mi duda!! buen dia!!

Answer (score 1):

Puede definir el `Tab Order` indicando cual es el componente que toma foco en primer lugar

[Visual Studio Tips and Tricks: How to set Tab Order of Windows Forms controls in Visual Studio](http://deepak-sharma.net/2012/12/11/visual-studio-tips-and-tricks-how-to-set-tab-order-of-windows-forms-controls-in-visual-studio/)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]